# Sort each sublist in a nested list

Tags: python, list, sorting

Example:

if given:

`list1 = [[4,2],[9,4],[3,7],[7,3],[2,6],[1,4]]`

And I want to get them sorted smallest to largest like:

`[[2,4],[4,9],[3,7],[3,7],[2,6],[1,4]]`

The order of those lists inside the list don't matter. In the end, I only want to have every core element to have the same combination. like [3,7] and [3,7] instead of [3,7] and [7,3]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is mapping with `sorted`:

```
list(map(sorted, list1))
# [[2, 4], [4, 9], [3, 7], [3, 7], [2, 6], [1, 4]]
```

Which is the same as doing:

```
[sorted(i) for i in list1]
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends:

- if you want to preserve the original data, i.e., obtain a new object containing new sublists, you can use the solution proposed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58561375/2749397)

  ```
  list1 = [[4,2],[9,4],[3,7],[7,3],[2,6],[1,4]]
  list2 = [sorted(sublist) for sublist in list1]
  ```

  but note that this comes with a cost, because you have to allocate new memory for the new sub-lists and the outer container, and also a non-negligible slow down;
- if you need not the original data after the sort operation you can use the fact that list objects are mutable and it is hence possible do the sort in place

  ```
  for sublist in list1: sublist.sort()
  ```

  this 2nd approach has the merit of not requiring additional memory and it's a little bit faster but of course if you afterwards need the original data...

---

I mentioned that `.sort()` is faster than `sorted()`, essentially due to the allocation of new memory, so let me present a little, naïf benchmark using IPython's `%timeit` magic

```
In [25]: l1 = [i for i in range(100000)]                                        

In [26]: %timeit -c -n 30 -r 20 (shuffle(l1) or l1)                             
119 ms ± 1.52 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 20 runs, 30 loops each)

In [27]: %timeit -c -n 30 -r 20 sorted(shuffle(l1) or l1)                       
154 ms ± 1.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 20 runs, 30 loops each)

In [28]: %timeit -c -n 30 -r 20 (shuffle(l1) or l1).sort()                      
148 ms ± 2.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 20 runs, 30 loops each)

In [29]: print("%.3f%%"%(100*(154-148)/(148-119)))                                     
20.690%
```